# What's the difference between get_new_rowversion() and @@DBTS

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Does anyone know what's the difference between **get_new_rowversion()** and **@@DBTS**?

I couldn't find any documentation about `get_new_rowversion()` which some article on internet say is a SQL Azure only function.

I also tried to run them in MSSQLLocalDB, SQL server and SQL Azure. They seem to return the same value.

But I'm not sure if they are equivalent functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have any technical documentation or credible resource at hand, but I'll try answer this based on my experience with Azure.

`@@DBTS` and `get_new_rowversion()` are expected to return same result, but are used in different environment.

For the uninitiated I'd suggest MSDN reference for [`@@DBTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187366.aspx) to understand it better. While you are it please note it's behavior inside a transaction and compare/contrast it with `MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()`

Quoting MSDN @@DBTS

> Returns the value of the current timestamp data type for the **current database**. This timestamp is guaranteed to be **unique in the database**.

Please note the word **current database**. So if you have mirroring on your database, and there are 2 mirrors and a primary database, you'd expect to have three different values for **`@@DBTS`**, one for each database.

When you do use mirroring, you'd have to be careful with using @@DBTS.

`get_new_rowversion()` is a function which returns the rowversion from the current DB in SQL Azure.

It's only available in SQL Azure and will not work else where.

You'd get a message like

> Could not find stored procedure 'GET_NEW_ROWVERSION'.

in other versions.

The reason for it's existence is because behind the scenes of SQLAzure, the sync framework may maintain multiple copies of DB(mirrors) for ensure quick response from mirrors in case of primary fails.  As two different DBs may have different counters for time, the value of `rowversion` will be different for them.

It then becomes important for SQL Azure to return user/TSQL with correct value for `rowversion` without user/it knowing whether user/TSQL is dealing with secondary or primary DB instance.

So thumb rules are:

1. Use `@@DBTS` on non-SQL Azure versions as `GET_NEW_ROWVERSION` is not
   defined.
2. Use `GET_NEW_ROWVERSION` on SQL Azure as you do not know which
   DB mirror may service your request and you'd get unexpected values
   from `@@DBTS`

Comment: If I'm not using any SQL Azure sync features (e.g replica), can I assume replacing **get_new_rowversion()** with **@@DBTS** should have the same behavior? (I'm migrating a SQL Azure to MSLocalDB)

Comment: AFAI understand you plan to use MS Local DB in a IaaS scenario. Then @@DBTS would work for you, also by thumb rule #1 get_new_rowversion should error out too.

Comment: The MSLocalDB is used for functional testing. Maybe I should say "recreate" instead of "migrate". Anyway, thanks for your response, it's helpful!